# Superposition of waves for changing frequency

Tags: waves, frequency, interference, superposition, models

Is this physically correct statement that the "superposition of waves increases with increasing frequency". An increase in frequency means smaller wavelength --> smaller path differences to lead from constructive to destructive differences. With fixed height and distance between two sources,  (let's consider a two-path model scenario) for a fixed angular range will it imply that we will see more nulls and maxima with the increase in frequency?

Thanks

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are asking here. Can you describe in more detail the scenario you are thinking of?

Comment: I am thinking of a two-path model scenario.

Comment: A diagram would be very helpful, I think.  I can't quite understand what sort of scenario you're thinking of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this physically correct statement that the "superposition of waves increases with increasing frequency"

No. Superposition just means that you can add the effect two waves. That's completely independent of the wave length.

What you probably mean is "complexity of the interference pattern" of two waves. This depends on wave length, size and distance of sources, the size reflection or diffracting objects and distance, but the exact relationships are complicated. Things tend to be the easiest to calculate if the wavelength is either very large or very small compared to all the other stuff.